# How to solve $y = \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots

Can the following equation be solved for x?

$$
y=  \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}
$$

*This is not actually homework - it comes from part of the rate law for a [particular chemical reaction](http://books.google.com/books?id=rhy6VRDmxHAC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=amino%20acid%20racemization%20rate%20law&source=bl&ots=o5uX8xOp3E&sig=ALlyPWKTyQqACRIWcfB7LV741EU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=THHGT7mgNois8ASt0rXVBg&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=amino%20acid%20racemization%20rate%20law&f=false) I am studying - but like a homework question, I'd be happy with pointers / strategies for the solution. I ought to be able to do this on my own, but today I'm making no progress!

Comment: Take exponentials of both sides. Then multiple across by $1-x$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$e^y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

$$e^y-1=(e^y+1)x$$

$$x=\frac{e^{y}-1}{e^{y}+1}$$

Answer (score 11):

Taking the exponential, we have
$$\begin{align*}
y &= \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\\
e^y &= \frac{1+x}{1-x}\\
e^y(1-x) &= 1+x\\
e^y -1 &= x + e^yx\\
e^y - 1 &= x(1+e^y)\\
\frac{e^y - 1}{e^y+1} &= x.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 8):

There is the "special" function

$$\tanh^{-1} x = \frac 1 2 \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

which is the inverse of

$$\tanh x = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

So what you want is

$$2\tanh^{-1} x =y$$

or

$$x=\tanh \frac{y}{2}$$

Comment: As I see it $\operatorname{tanh}^{-1}=\operatorname{arctanh}$ is en elementary function. But sure every function is "Special" in a weak sense. :)

Comment: @AD. That's why the put it between " "

Answer (score 3):

Just consider the inverse function of $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ that is $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$. After taking exponential of both sides, place each of the sides in the inverse function and get the final result.
$$ \frac{e^y - 1}{e^y+1} = x $$
The proof is complete.